# Can AWS X-Ray be configured to work in a multi-container Beanstalk application?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-xray

I am trying to get AWS X-Ray working in a multi-container Beanstalk app as described [in the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html). I found a community-built X-Ray container which I can run alongside my app: [pottava/xray:2.0](https://hub.docker.com/r/pottava/xray/). According to `docker stats` and `docker ps` this container is running and receiving/sending network traffic (the traces are sent via UDP to the container). But there is no tracing data showing up in the AWS console.

I have not enabled X-Ray via a `.ebextensions/` config file as suggested [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-debugging.html#environment-configuration-debugging-namespace). Trying this failed the deployment to Beanstalk. In fact, the multi-container environment is not listed as a [supported platform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-debugging.html). So while plenty of docs mention using X-Ray on Beanstalk, I am not sure if there is a way to configure this on my multi-Docker environment.

- Can X-Ray configured in multi-Docker Beanstalk? If yes, how?
- What's the best way to troubleshoot the collection & delivery of traces?

Answer (score 2):

The community-built Docker container to which you've linked should work as desired in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Have you added the necessary `AWSXrayWriteOnlyAccess` managed policy to your Elastic Beanstalk instance profile?

To further troubleshoot, please find the AWS X-Ray daemon logs from within the daemon's Docker container. The log will report any attempted calls to the `PutTraceSegments` API, as well as any errors which may result. In the linked Docker container, this [file is located at `/var/log/xray-daemon.log`](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2012/10/c_c_tip_how_detect_compiler_name_and_version_using_compiler_predefined_macros).

Answer (score 1):

> - **Can X-Ray configured in multi-Docker Beanstalk? If yes, how?**

Yes, *but* it's not as simple as the X-ray daemon that can be enabled via .ebextensions as described in [Running the X-Ray daemon on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html). That won't work on Docker platforms (without significant networking hacks). According to the article,
`Elastic Beanstalk does not provide the X-Ray daemon on the Multicontainer Docker (Amazon ECS) platform`.  Also, it's worth noting that neither Docker platform is listed under *Supported Platforms* in the article, [Configuring AWS X-Ray debugging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-debugging.html).

For the `Docker` platform (Amazon Linux 2), you can use docker-compose to run the X-ray daemon in a container alongside your application. Here is a simple example of the `docker-compose.yml` that I use in a simple API app:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    api: # my app instrumented with the AWS X-Ray SDK
        build: 
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile-awseb
        ports:
            - "80:3000"
        environment:
            - AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS=xray:2000
        env_file: .env
    xray:
        image: "amazon/aws-xray-daemon"
```

For the `Multicontainer` platform, the Scorekeep example in the article, [Instrumenting Amazon ECS applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/scorekeep-ecs.html), shows a more elaborate example of instrumenting in a multicontainer Docker environment in Elastic Beanstalk.

> - **What's the best way to troubleshoot the collection & delivery of traces?**

Some high-level tips...

- Enable pre-requisite permissions as described in [the X-Ray Getting Started article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-gettingstarted.html#xray-gettingstarted-prereqs) (viz., `AWSXrayFullAccess`).
- Check the X-ray daemon logs (which are configured differently in the [Scorekeep multicontainer example](https://github.com/aws-samples/eb-java-scorekeep/blob/xray-ecs/task-definition/template/scorekeep-dockerrun.template) from the [X-Ray daemon on Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html)).
- Use the [X-ray Analytics console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-console-analytics.html) to confirm whether it's receiving traces.

When using a supported platform, you might find additional guidance in [Configuring AWS X-Ray debugging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/environment-configuration-debugging.html).

Comment: I found this out the hard way, while unsuccessfully attempting to use the [.ebextensions configuration for AWS X-ray daemon](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-beanstalk.html) on a single-container Docker runtime. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53980295) is a helpful example of working through that situation