# XRay Traces not showing up in AWS Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-xray

I've followed the AWS documentation on setting up XRAY for our Spring Boot application deployed on AWS ECS, but I'm not able to see the traces for my services in the AWS Console.  Here's a high level view of the changes I've implemented:

Added Role with Policy permissions to my EC2

```
"xray:BatchGetTraces",
"xray:GetServiceGraph",
"xray:GetTraceGraph",
"xray:GetTraceSummaries",
"xray:PutTelemetryRecords",
"xray:PutTraceSegments"
```

Added Tracing filter

```
@Bean
public Filter TracingFilter() {
    return new AWSXRayServletFilter("myService");
}
```

Added XRAY dependencies to our POM file and added *@XRayEnabled* annotation to our Controller method:

Downloaded the XRAY Daemon to our ec2 instance and installed

```
curl https://s3.dualstack.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/aws-xray-assets.us-east-1/xray-daemon/aws-xray-daemon-3.x.rpm -o /home/ec2-user/xray.rpm
yum install -y /home/ec2-user/xray.rpm
```

I've verified that we are seeing UDP logging statements for example:
com.amazonaws.xray.emitters.UDPEmitter:

```
 {
  "name" : "myService",
  "id" : "1234",
  "start_time" : 1.546020031234E9,
  "trace_id" : "myTraceId",
  "end_time" : 1.546020031234E9,
  "http" : {
    "request" : {
      "method" : "POST",
      "client_ip" : "myIp",
      "url" : "myURL",
      "user_agent" : "PostmanRuntime/7.4.0",
      "x_forwarded_for" : true
    },
    "response" : {
      "content_length" : 200,
      "status" : 200
    }
  },
  "aws" : {
    "xray" : {
      "sdk_version" : "1.2.1",
      "sdk" : "X-Ray for Java"
    }
  },
  "service" : {
    "runtime" : "OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM",
    "runtime_version" : "1.8.0_151"
  }
}
```

And I've also verified that the daemon is running on the ec2 using netstat -tulpn

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:2000          0.0.0.0:*                           14126/xray
```

What else is needed to be able to get the XRAY traces to show up in the AWS Console?

I've started the docker daemon with logging enabled, but I'm not seeing any indication that the docker daemon is sending data to AWS, just startup information and that's it:

```
2018-12-28T23:14:19Z [Info] Initializing AWS X-Ray daemon 3.0.0
2018-12-28T23:14:19Z [Info] Using buffer memory limit of 304 MB
2018-12-28T23:14:19Z [Info] 4864 segment buffers allocated
2018-12-28T23:14:19Z [Info] Using region: us-east-1
2018-12-28T23:14:19Z [Info] Starting proxy http server on 127.0.0.1:2000
```

Comment: I believe that what is happening is the data is not getting from the task to the host ec2 daemon, but I'm not sure how to verify that is the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am guessing the issue is because you are running X-Ray Daemon on EC2 host and your java container is trying to send events to `127.0.0.1:2000` by default which is inside the java container itself but not the host address. Docker container sees `127.0.0.1` as within the container scope.

You will need to configure the X-Ray Daemon Address properly on your Java App.

> AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS – Set the host and port of the X-Ray daemon
> listener. By default, the SDK uses 127.0.0.1:2000 for both trace data
> (UDP) and sampling (TCP). Use this variable if you have configured the
> daemon to listen on a different port or if it is running on a
> different host.
>
> Format
>
> Same port – address:port
>
> Different ports – tcp:address:port udp:address:port

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-sdk-java-configuration.html#xray-sdk-java-configuration-envvars

Since you are instrumenting the ECS based application, I would advise to spin up X-Ray Daemon as Docker Container but not as actual process on EC2 host.

Example -

1. Run the X-Ray Daemon as ECS Container(As Daemon scheduling type).
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/xray-daemon-ecs.html
   https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ecs_services.html#service_scheduler
2. Based on which networking model you are using on ECS, you should be able to interact with X-Ray container Address and Port from your java container.

Let me know if you have any questions.

## Update -

X-RAY Daemon as a Docker Container vs running it on the host?

It's just some opinion and it seems like some recommended way from AWS. Few advantages I can think of are

1. You don't have to maintain scripts/sequence for bringing X-Ray Daemon process part of your EC2 AMI.
2. You don't have to give whole EC2 Role permission to send data to X-Ray but with container, only that particular task role has permissions and not everything else.
3. If the process is stopped due to any reason, you have to manually bring up process or remove EC2 from cluster or maintain complex scripts on AMI. But with being ECS managed container, it will make sure task is running always.
4. ECS Daemon scheduling documentation says your case is why they brought this type of containers.

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/06/amazon-ecs-adds-daemon-scheduling/

Again, this is just my opinion but you can go with desired way as well.

Comment: Thanks Imran.  Can you elaborate on why you would advise to spin up X-RAY Daemon as a Docker Container vs running it on the host?  I don't have a preference, but just want to understand the pro's and con's in this case.

Comment: @greenJavaDev  There are pro's and con's, I have updated my answer with some good pro's. You can go with desired way as well. :) Please upvote and accept answer if you are ok.

Comment: I tried three options based on your answer and none of them worked unfortunately

1) setting com.amazonaws.xray.emitters.daemonAddress=127.0.0.1:2000 
2) setting com.amazonaws.xray.emitters.daemonAddress=127.0.0.1:2000  and using docker option -p 2000:2000
3) just using -p 2000:2000 without daemonAddress set

Comment: also 4) -p 2000:2000 -p 2000:2000/udp + daemon address.  I'm going to try to read up more on docker networking and also implement Daemon scheduling on ECS

Comment: Are you using any service discovery in ECS cluster where each service can talk to each other?. Route53?. Consul?. etcd?. which networking type you are using in the cluster?. awsvpc or default(bridge) ?

Comment: For testing purpose, you can still keep x-ray as daemon on EC2 host and configure EC2 privateip or private dns name as your `AWS_XRAY_DAEMON_ADDRESS`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185988/discussion-between-imran-and-greenjavadev).

Comment: I'm accepting this solution because I feel that deploying the daemon as a separate docker container is the answer to my original problem.  I still have some issues getting the docker daemon container approach to work, but I don't feel it would be appropriate to tack those on here, so it will be a separate question

Comment: tried to run as docker container, but it is still not working

Comment: An example of running the X-Ray daemon on ECS is available at [Instrumenting Amazon ECS applications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/xray/latest/devguide/scorekeep-ecs.html).  To instrument a simple multi-container app on the Docker platform (Amazon Linux 2) on Elastic Beanstalk, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67287691/430202).